# Github API generated annotated tag not showing up in git describe

Tags: python-3.x, git, github-api, pygithub

I am trying to write a script to automatically setup github releases using a custom CI trigger. I have a python script that uses `pygithub` to automatically create a tag and a release.

```
# roughly the following code:
repo.create_git_tag(...)
repo.create_git_ref(...)
repo.create_git_release(...)
```

After running the script, everything shows up in the GitHub web UI, after a `git fetch origin && git tag -l`, I can see the tags locally. But when I use `git describe` (even with `--tags`), it fails with `fatal: No tags can describe '<head_commit_hash>'`

Using `git show-ref --tags`, I get something like the following:

```
hash1 refs/tags/releases/1.0.0
hash2 refs/tags/releases/1.1.0
hash3 refs/tags/releases/1.1.1
```

Then `git cat-file -p hash1` gives me:

```
object hash_of_commit_at_tag
type commit
tag releases/1.0.0
tagger ...

Release: 1.0.0
```

But if I create and push the tag myself using `git tag -a releases/1.0.0 hash_of_commit -m "Release 1.0.0"`, the `git describe` gives me the last reachable tag from my current `HEAD`.

Question is, is `GitHub api` or `pygithub` doing anything special? Or am I missing an api call in `pygithub`?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the GitHub API is creating un-annotated tags when you make a release.

The solution that works for me is to use `git describe --tags`

THis is from my repo with two tags created by making a release in the GitHub API

```
❯ git tag -l
v1.1.0
v1.2.0
❯ git describe
fatal: No annotated tags can describe '912268bd176bbda06983995894b46cf764b3e666'.
However, there were unannotated tags: try --tags.
❯ git describe --tags
v1.2.0
```